# Rust Snafu Missing 'source' field

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm trying to use the snafu crate for error handling, but keep getting erros that my Error enum struct is missing the 'source' and that `IntoError` is not implimented for `Error`:

```rust
//main.rs
use snafu::{ResultExt, Snafu};
#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
#[snafu(visibility = "pub(crate)")]
pub enum Error{
    #[snafu(display("Could not load gallery JSON: {}: {}", json_path, source))]
    LoadGallery {
        source: std::io::Error,
        json_path: String,
    },
}
```

```rust
//gallery.rs
use snafu::{ResultExt}; 
use crate::Error::{LoadGallery};

pub struct Gallery{
    name: String,
}

impl Gallery{
    pub fn from_json(json_path: String)->Result<()>{
        let configuration = std::fs::read_to_string(&json_path).context(LoadGallery { json_path })?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

results in:

```
let configuration = std::fs::read_to_string(&json_path).context(LoadGallery { json_path })?;
|                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `source`
let configuration = std::fs::read_to_string(&json_path).context(LoadGallery { json_path })?;
|                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `IntoError<_>` is not implemented for `Error`
```

Based on this example from the docs, I don't see what I'm doing wrong:

```rust
use snafu::{ResultExt, Snafu};
use std::{fs, io, path::PathBuf};

#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
enum Error {
    #[snafu(display("Unable to read configuration from {}: {}", path.display(), source))]
    ReadConfiguration { source: io::Error, path: PathBuf },

    #[snafu(display("Unable to write result to {}: {}", path.display(), source))]
    WriteResult { source: io::Error, path: PathBuf },
}

type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

fn process_data() -> Result<()> {
    let path = "config.toml";
    let configuration = fs::read_to_string(path).context(ReadConfiguration { path })?;
    let path = unpack_config(&configuration);
    fs::write(&path, b"My complex calculation").context(WriteResult { path })?;
    Ok(())
}

fn unpack_config(data: &str) -> &str {
    "/some/path/that/does/not/exist"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you're constructing `LoadGallery`, you're attempting to construct `Error::LoadGallery`. You then get a compile error saying "missing `source`", because the `Error::LoadGallery` variant has a `source` field. Fixing it is straight forward, you just need to change which `LoadGallery` you import.

```rust
// Not this one:
// use crate::Error::LoadGallery;

// This one:
use crate::LoadGallery;
```

Why? Because [`snafu`](https://crates.io/crates/snafu) generates a `struct` for each of `Error`'s variants. So there's a `struct LoadGallery` being generated. This struct doesn't contain the `source` field, which is why you can construct it without `source` and pass it to [`context()`](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.6.10/snafu/trait.ResultExt.html#tymethod.context), because it's not actually `Error::LoadGallery`.

Your `from_json()` also needs to return `Result<(), Error>` instead of `Result<()>` (you don't have the type alias, like in the example.)

```rust
use crate::{Error, LoadGallery};
use snafu::ResultExt;

pub struct Gallery {
    name: String,
}

impl Gallery {
    pub fn from_json(json_path: String) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let configuration =
            std::fs::read_to_string(&json_path).context(LoadGallery { json_path })?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

If you're curious you can use [`cargo expand`](https://crates.io/crates/expand) to inspect what macros expand to. You first need to install it by doing `cargo install expand`. Then you can execute [`cargo expand`](https://crates.io/crates/expand) in any project.